# Changes In main.Dart not reflecting insted showing previous code changes

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

When I done some changes in main.Dart of simple HelloWorld program ,new changes are not reflecting in my mobile.Old UI changes are reflecting.I have restarted my visual studio editor, uninstall app.Still old UI changes are reflecting.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio provide terminal in bottom,
type Flutter run
then you will see ..

```
Launching lib/main.dart on SM G615F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        16.8s
✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
Syncing files to device SM G615F...                                     
D/GraphicBuffer(24157): register, handle(0xddbb3680) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:b00)
Syncing files to device SM G615F...                              5,356ms (!)                                       

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload. 
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).
```

Type r

```
Initializing hot reload...                                              
Reloaded 0 of 483 libraries in 523ms.
D/GraphicBuffer(24157): register, handle(0xddbb3920) (w:1080 h:1920 s:1088 f:0x1 u:b00)
```

After that Type R .

```
Performing hot restart...                                               

Restarted application in 2,067ms.
```

Changes are reflecting.Issue get resolved

Answer (score 0):

if your code don't reflect on your UI or real device , you can move to master channel of flutter then run flutter clean

you can move to master channel by run in terminal :

> flutter channel master